# GeoServer - Error while storing uploaded file

Tags: python, geoserver

I am suddenly unable to load new geotiff files into an old GeoServer instance (2.15.2).

The latest log entries are:

```
2021-06-01 12:27:16,920 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null https://geoserver.test.edu/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/rtofs:rtofs_qf_20171123_0000@EPSG:4326@jpeg/10
2021-06-01 12:27:16,920 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Request failed
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2021-06-01 12:36:44,743 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null https://geoserver.test.edu/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/rtofs:rtofs_qf_20180323_0000@EPSG:900913@png/16
2021-06-01 12:36:44,743 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Request failed
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2021-06-01 12:38:41,224 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - Error while storing uploaded file:
org.geoserver.rest.RestException 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: Error while storing uploaded file:
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.AbstractStoreUploadController.handleFileUpload(AbstractStoreUploadController.java:93)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.doFileUpload(CoverageStoreFileController.java:451)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePut(CoverageStoreFileController.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor550.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:912)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:437)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    a2021-08-19 15:21:54,602 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - null https://132.177.103.242/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/gomofs:gomofs_qf_20200316_0000@EPSG:900913@png/8
2021-08-19 15:21:54,602 ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Request failed
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
2021-08-19 15:21:56,818 ERROR [geoserver.rest] - Error while storing uploaded file:
org.geoserver.rest.RestException 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: Error while storing uploaded file:
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.AbstractStoreUploadController.handleFileUpload(AbstractStoreUploadController.java:93)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.doFileUpload(CoverageStoreFileController.java:451)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePut(CoverageStoreFileController.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor550.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:912)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:437)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatc2021-09-17 15:37:09,554 WARN [geoserver.web] - Error saving authentication config
com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException: 
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.flush(QuickWriter.java:77)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.write(QuickWriter.java:49)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.writeText(PrettyPrintWriter.java:279)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.writeAttributeValue(PrettyPrintWriter.java:227)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.addAttribute(PrettyPrintWriter.java:222)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager$FilterChainConverter.marshal(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:3415)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:274)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:250)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.<init>(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:213)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:144)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:90)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1319)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1308)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:1281)
    at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamPersister.save(XStreamPersister.java:663)
    at org.geoserver.config.util.XStreamUtils.xStreamPersist(XStreamUtils.java:68)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager.saveSecurityConfig(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:1608)
    at org.geoserver.security.web.auth.AuthenticationPage$4.onSubmit(AuthenticationPage.java:229)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1309)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:708)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http
```

Running a stable script, I now get:

```
  File "C:\Users\geoserver\AppData\Local\HyOc\lib\site-packages\geoserver\catalog.py", line 462, in create_coveragestore
    self._create_coveragestore(name, data, workspace, overwrite)
  File "C:\Users\geoserver\AppData\Local\HyOc\lib\site-packages\geoserver\catalog.py", line 524, in _create_coveragestore
    raise UploadError(r.text)
geoserver.catalog.UploadError: Error while storing uploaded file:
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: is it possible that the disk is full?

Comment: Any updates on this issue??

Comment: Yep, the disk was full as suggested by Ian.